# Need SQL Query According To month and Year from Same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 2 Table 
InvoiceDetail as

```
--------------------------------------------
|  Id    | Invoicesubdt | Amount  | Orgid  |
|   1    | 02-05-2017    | 100    |  29    |
|   2    | 08-06-2019   | 1200    |  30    | 
--------------------------------------------
```

Orgdetial

```
-----------------------------
|  Id   |  company_name     |
|  29   |  company..        |
|   30  |  Company1         |
-----------------------------
```

For Join

```
Orgdetial.Id=InvoiceDetail.Orgid
```

I Need the Result as

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Company_name   | Total_Amount   |  Month  |  Year |
| Company1       | 100000         |  10     | 2018  |



  SELECT YEAR(InvoiceSubDt)as Years, MONTH(InvoiceSubDt) as Months , sum (Amount)  AS TOTALCOUNT 
    FROM InvoiceDetail 
    GROUP BY YEAR(InvoiceSubDt), MONTH(InvoiceSubDt)
```

Comment: Thanks for telling us what you *need*, but what is your question? Stack Overflow is a Q&A website, not a Free Coding Service. If you have a question, please do ask one.

Comment: I simply cannot imagine how your result is derived from your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(InvoiceSubDt)as Years, 
  MONTH(InvoiceSubDt) as Months , 
  sum (Amount)  AS TOTALCOUNT 
FROM InvoiceDetail 
INNER JOIN Orgdetial ON Orgdetial.Id=InvoiceDetail.Orgid
GROUP BY YEAR(InvoiceSubDt), MONTH(InvoiceSubDt)
```